# Using TI Linker Command File with Clang

Tags: c++, clang, msp430

When using TI (Texas Instrument) compiler, I am able to set a memory location of embedded micro-controller using C++ by simply `ADC12IFG = 50;`.  Clang marks this code as error: `indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)`.  So when I dig into it, TI has a header file, msp430f5335.h which has the following lines:

```
#define SFR_16BIT(address)  extern volatile unsigned int address
SFR_16BIT(ADC12IFG);                          /* ADC12+ Interrupt Flag */
```

Then there is a linker command file, msp430f5335.cmd which has the following line:

```
ADC12IFG           = 0x070A;
```

So it looks like the linker command file specifies the `address`.  So is it possible to have clang analysis tool recognize the linker command file and not cause a false positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clang is intended to be GCC compatible.

TI's header files ([`msp430-gcc-support-files`](http://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSPGCC/latest/index_FDS.html)) use the following mechanism to define memory-mapped register variables:

```
#define sfrw_(x,x_) extern volatile unsigned int x asm(#x_)
#define sfrw(x,x_) sfrw_(x,x_)

#define ADC12IFG_             0x070A    /* ADC12+ Interrupt Flag */
sfrw(ADC12IFG, ADC12IFG_);
```

(This does not require a linker command file.)